# popup issue in chrome new version 37

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am not able to open popup in Chrome new version.
I click on a link which opens the modal dialog popup but the popup does not appear.
I am guessing it is a problem with google chrome new version.

```
function DownloadReport() {
    window.document.getElementById("MainContent_hfRefresh").value = "True";
    showmodalDialog("../../General/DownLoad/Download.aspx", 1024, 500);
}
```

This code working fine in older version 36.

Comment: Please show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: function DownloadReport() {
            window.document.getElementById("MainContent_hfRefresh").value = "True";
            showmodalDialog("../../General/DownLoad/Download.aspx", 1024, 500);
 
        }


This code working fine in older version 36.

Comment: The [window.showModalDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.showModalDialog) is deprecated ([Intent to Remove: window.showModalDialog()](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/xh9fPX0ijqk/ixHZCOH6GLgJ), [Removing showModalDialog from the Web platform](https://dev.opera.com/blog/showmodaldialog/)). `[...]The latest plan is to land the showModalDialog removal in Chromium 37. This means the feature will be gone in Opera 24 and Chrome 37, both of which should be released in September.[...]`

Comment: Hi t,niese "window.showModalDialog" it's not working - actually

Comment: The code you show would not even work with browsers that will still support `showModalDialog`, as you write it with a lowercase `m`. That's what I tried to say with that. I replace it with a cite of the links I provided with my comment, as you seems not to read it yourself.

Comment: http://thenextweb.com/google/2014/08/26/chrome-37-launches-directwrite-support-better-looking-fonts-windows-revamped-password-manager/
showModalDialog has been deprecated in version 37 with plans to remove May 2015, there's a 'patch' link above that will allow you to override that until then, but then you'll need to adjust

Answer (score 0):

finally I use jquery dialog replace window.showModalDialog():
parrent page:

```
            var href = "test.html"
            var obj = jQuery('#chooseTaskDlg');
            if(!obj)
                return false;
            obj.html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + href + '" width="100%" height="99%"></iframe>');
            obj.dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        height:780,
                        width:950,
                        modal: true,
                        close: function(){
                            if(undefined != dialogRet && '' != dialogRet) 
                            {
                                //do something with the string dialogRet 
                            }
                            return null;
                        }
                    });
            obj.dialog('open');
```

then in child page "test.html":

```
if (isNeedIeModalDialog())   //IE
{
    obj = window.dialogArguments;
    window.returnValue = someValue;
}
else
{
    obj = window.opener ? window.opener : parent;
    obj.dialogRet = someValue;
}
obj.document.getElementById(type + '_ipinfo').value=someValue; //do something with parrent document
closeModalWindow('chooseTaskDlg');
```

Comment: realy with this code your problem with showmodalDialog solved?

Comment: @Cyrec can you make workable demo for same,since i had tried your code but not works as expected.